# SQL max function get other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, max, aggregate-functions

I have a simple relation "sea" with only two columns, one is called "name" and the other "depth". With the following command, I can output the number maximum number in the attribute depth:

```
SELECT max(depth) FROM sea;
```

I am trying to get the the name of the maximum depth as well, such that it outputs:

```
    name | depth
___________________
pacific  | 11034
```

Is there a way to output that as well?

I have tried it with group by and also by trying to JOIN the table with itself receiving the other attributes, that did not find any solution.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `order by`:

```
select s.*
from sea s
order by s.depth desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  Some databases do not support `fetch` -- the standard SQL syntax -- so you might use `limit` or `select top (1)` or some similar construct.

The above returns exactly one row, even if there are ties.  If you want *all* rows, then a simple method is a subquery:

```
select s.*
from seas s
where s.depth = (select max(s2.depth) from seas s2);
```

Comment: Actually, the second one is exactly what I wanted to use, thank you! The first one works as well